# Debugging ES6 code in NodeJs and WebStorm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, debugging, webstorm

I am .Net developer and new in NodeJs. The first point to start learning this - [this](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) template. This is the most popular template. And the first thing I wanted to have - debugging code in some IDE, because I am used to IDE (Visual studio). Debugging in WebTools is awfull. Your server code is written using ES6 and Babel. And I have invested some time to make it debuggable in IDE. I have chosen Webstorm (last version) for it.

I have generated project with such options

generator-angular-fullstack | 3.7.2

Node | 5.10.1

npm | 3.8.3

Operating System | Windows 8.1

Transpiler | TypeScript

Markup |  Jade

CSS |  LESS

Router |  ui-router

Build Tool |  Gulp

Client Tests |  Mocha

DB | MongoDB

Auth | Y

Neither WebStrom nor VisualStudio Code cannot debug ES6. That's why I need to transpile server in ES5 during development. I did it in `.tmpsrv` folder. For that reason I have added new variable to `paths` object in `gulpfile.babel.js`:

```
 tmpsrv: '.tmpsrv'
```

Also I have created some gulp tasks and added them in `gulpfile.babel.js` :

```
// web storm tasks

// transiles server in ES5 to .tmpsrv folder
gulp.task('transpile:server:ide', () => {
    return gulp.src(_.union(paths.server.scripts, paths.server.json))
        .pipe(transpileServer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.tmpsrv}/${serverPath}`));
});

// clean .tmpsrv folder
gulp.task('clean:tmpsrv', () => del(['.tmpsrv/**/*'], {dot: true}));

// set 'developmentIde' variable
gulp.task('env:ide', () => {
    plugins.env({
        vars: {NODE_ENV: 'developmentIde'}
    });
});

// prepares all stuff for debugging in WebStorm
gulp.task('serve:ide', cb => {
    runSequence(['clean:tmp','clean:tmpsrv', 'constant', 'env:all','env:ide', 'typings'],
        ['lint:scripts', 'inject', 'jade'],
        ['wiredep:client'],
        ['transpile:client', 'styles','transpile:server:ide'],

        cb);
});
```

Now, if I fire `gulp:serve:ide` task, .`tmp`folder with transpiled client and `.tmpsrv` folder with transpiled server and source maps wiil be created (but you SHOULD NOT do it right now). `index.js` of the server in this folder will be startup file for debugging session in WebStrom ( this IDE can debug ES6 with source maps, if we start debugging session for ES5 code and put breakpoints in ES6 code). As you see I will start my server from `.tmpsrv`  folder during debugging, that is why I need to modify some paths and settings in projects.

First of all I go to `server/config/environment/index.js` and add such code in `all`object:

```
// Root path of transpiled server
transpiledRoot: path.normalize(__dirname + '/../../../..'),
```

Than I add file 'developmentIde.js' in `server/config/express.js' folder and copy contents of`server/config/environment/development.js' there.

Then I go to `server/config/express.js'  and replace this:

```
app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
```

with this:

```
if ('development' === env || 'test' === env)
{
  app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
}
else
{
  app.set('views', config.transpiledRoot + '/server/views');
}
```

Also I replace this:

```
app.set('appPath', path.join(config.root, 'client'));
```

with this:

```
if('developmentIde' === env){
  app.set('appPath', path.join(config.transpiledRoot, 'client'));
} else{
  app.set('appPath', path.join(config.root, 'client'));
}
```

Also I replace this:

```
if ('development' === env) {
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
    ignore: [
      /^\/api\/(.*)/,
      /\.js(\?.*)?$/, /\.css(\?.*)?$/, /\.svg(\?.*)?$/, /\.ico(\?.*)?$/, /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,
      /\.png(\?.*)?$/, /\.jpg(\?.*)?$/, /\.jpeg(\?.*)?$/, /\.gif(\?.*)?$/, /\.pdf(\?.*)?$/
    ]
  }));
}
```

with this:

```
if ('development' === env || 'developmentIde' === env) {
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
    ignore: [
      /^\/api\/(.*)/,
      /\.js(\?.*)?$/, /\.css(\?.*)?$/, /\.svg(\?.*)?$/, /\.ico(\?.*)?$/, /\.woff(\?.*)?$/,
      /\.png(\?.*)?$/, /\.jpg(\?.*)?$/, /\.jpeg(\?.*)?$/, /\.gif(\?.*)?$/, /\.pdf(\?.*)?$/
    ]
  }));
}
```

Also I replace this:

```
if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(app.get('appPath')));
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
}
```

with this:

```
if ('development' === env || 'test' === env || 'developmentIde' === env) {
  if('developmentIde' === env){
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.transpiledRoot, '.tmp')));
  } else{
    app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
  }

  app.use(express.static(app.get('appPath')));
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
}
```

All this code makes my debugging server to find client content in right places. Also I need to transpile server for every code change in server scripts. That's why I go back to gulp file and replace modify code in `watch`task. I replace this:

```
plugins.watch(_.union(paths.server.scripts, testFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(lintServerScripts())
    .pipe(plugins.livereload());
```

with this:

```
plugins.watch(_.union(paths.server.scripts, testFiles, paths.server.json))
    .pipe(plugins.plumber())
    .pipe(transpileServer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(`${paths.tmpsrv}/${serverPath}`))
    .pipe(lintServerScripts())
    .pipe(plugins.livereload());
```

Finally I have to create `Run Configuration`, where start up file will be `.tmpsrv\server\index.js`, startup task will be `gulp:serve:ide` (or you can run it  manually). Also you have to set `NODE_ENV=developmentIde` for this run configuration. And during debug session `gulp:watch` task should work. Everything is working. Now you can debug this in WebStorm. But I am newbee in all that NodeJS and gulp stuff. Can somebody look at my modifications and propose better solutions? It is really a lot of things to modify, to establish ES6 debugging. I do not like my solution at all, and I do not believe, that NodeJS community has not already invented some more elegant solutions.

Comment: actually, Webstorm can debug ES6 (but you need to make sure that sourcemaps are there). So I'm not sure why you need all this stuff at all. What problems debugging ES6 have you faced? Are you trying to debug server-side or client-side code?

Comment: Server side. And I need all this stuff to transpile server with source maps. In fact,  all this stuff is gulp task,  which transpiles server on code changes,  and redefining template options.  Please tell me, how can I debug both sides in one session? Especially in case,  when I have es6 server and TypeScript client?

Comment: You can use Node.js run configuration to debug both sides using single run configuration - this configuration has 'Browser/live edit' tab where you can specify the server URL. The rest is just a matter of proper sourcemaps generation - you need generating them for both sides.  If you like to do everything in one step (transpiling both sides and starting the debugger for both), than your configuration should probably start gulp with the corresponding task